# Visualforce PDF rendering sans-serif font with bold elements in same section not working

Tags: css, pdf, renderas

I have a Visualforce page with a sans-serif font:

```
<apex:page
    showHeader="false"
    applyHtmlTag="false"
    applyBodyTag="false"
    standardStylesheets="false"
    controller="SignedRecordsReleaseV1"
    contentType="application/pdf"
    renderAs="pdf"
>

<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.bold {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    bold text
    <br />
    bold <b>text</b>
    <br />
    bold <span class="bold">text</span>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

The output of the above page doesn't have a mix of bold and non-bold text. The output appears as:

[image: salesforce bad pdf text render bold sans-serif]

It's unclear if this font is even bold. Note that there is no difference between the text marked as bold and the text marked as non-bold.

I've tried many things, such as setting the `font: Helvetica`, tried switching the font-family to `font-family: SansSerif;` based on [supported fonts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm) tried setting `font-weight: bold !important`, I've tried using outputText, as in:

```
bold <apex:outputText styleClass="bold" value="text"/>
```

Using a sans-serif font, is it possible to have bold text in a PDF?

Comment: How this page is rendering as an HTML? Is it rendering properly as desired?

Comment: Yes, the page renders generally fine as HTML. The PDF is generated as part of a background job, so we can't download the page as HTML in a browser